# Get coordinates of screen point on the map

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl

I'm using a MapBox GL map in my web application. It has some interactivity features that I handle through pointermove events. When the user moves the pointer over the map (it might also be outside the map, which has different functionality) I can show a custom marker element (simple `<div>`, position is absolute to the document) over the map where the pointer currently is. When the drag operation is completed, I need to know the map coordinates under that point.

So what I need is a method to convert a screen or document position (X, Y) to the coordinates (Lat, Lng) on the map in its current view state.

All I found was the `getCenter` method that gives me the center of the map (not the pointer positition) or the `project` method that seems to do the exact opposite of what I need. There also seems to be the map's "mousemove" event or similar, which could give me the coordinates in the event data, but I'm not using that event, because the drag operation could have started outside the map. Seems I need the reverse operation of the `project` method. Is there any?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging through the map's source code regarding the "mousemove" event, I found the `Map.unproject` method. It seems to be what I need. It wants x/y coordinates relative to the map element, not the document though. I just didn't find it and Google didn't know what I mean either. Maybe this answer teaches Google a bit more about possible search terms not mentioned elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks a lot, for typescript users,  method can be called the following way map.unproject(new mapboxgl.Point(x, y));  return type of the function is "mapboxgl.LngLat"